# Debian(amd64) Wheezy downgrading libsqlite3-0

Tags: sqlite

```
benben@debian:~/goagent$ sudo apt-get install sqlite3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
sqlite3 : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.7.13-1+deb7u1) but 3.7.17-1~bpo70+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How may I use `sqlite3`?

---

```
benben@debian:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep bpo | grep libsqlite
ri  libsqlite3-0:amd64                    3.7.17-1~bpo70+1                   amd64        SQLite 3 shared library
```

---

Here is the output of dependencies. It seems a lot of common packages depend on it.

I'm not sure about this, but I think maybe once I tried to install some package in unstable, which updated the `libsqlite3-0` package automatically.

How may I rescue?

```
benben@debian:~$ apt-cache --installed rdepends libsqlite3-0
libsqlite3-0
Reverse Depends:
  libnss3
  iceweasel
  libyelp0
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
  libtracker-sparql-0.14-0
  telepathy-salut
  telepathy-logger
  libtelepathy-logger2
  telepathy-gabble
  libseed-gtk3-0
  python3.2
  python2.7
  python2.6
  packagekit
  libpackagekit-glib2-14
  libnss3
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1
  libgpod4
  libchamplain-0.12-0
  iceweasel
  gnome-settings-daemon
  gnome-packagekit
  glchess
  libedataserverui-3.0-1
  libedata-book-1.2-13
  libebook-1.2-13
  libebackend-1.2-2
  libcamel-1.2-33
  evolution-data-server
  colord
  aptitude
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you're trying to achieve. You mentioned "downgrading" in the subject, but then you just posted `apt-get install` output. Posting `dpkg -l | grep sqlite` output may be useful.

Comment: Can we see the output of `dpkg -l | grep bpo` as well?  You have the backports repo enabled, and your `libsqlite3-0` has been installed from there.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. libsqlite3-0(3.7.17-1) is currently installed, which cause the failure to install sqlite3. So I want to downgrade it.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from your `dpkg -l` output, it looks like `libsqlite3-0-3.7.17-1~bpo70+1` has been selected for removal (`r`), but is still installed (`i`) for some reason. You can check if any of your installed packages depend on this package by running:

```
apt-cache --installed rdepends libsqlite3-0
```

If none of your installed packages depend on the problematic package, just purge it using:

```
apt-get purge libsqlite3-0
```

and then try installing `sqlite3` again.

Also, the `libsqlite3-0` package is *not* currently available from *wheezy-backports*, so if the above doesn't work, it might be a good idea to do an `apt-get update` and retry installing `sqlite3` afterwards.

Comment: See update above.

Comment: @wlnirvana Could you post the output of `apt-cache showpkg libsqlite3-0` as well? That way we'll be able to see which packages depend on the problematic version of `libsqlite3-0` and which have an "at least version *X.Y.Z*"-type dependency.

Comment: I reinstalled the entire system yesterday because I first dist-upgraded to Jessie to solve the problem, and then found my laptop was too old and slow to run Jessie, so I reinstall back to Wheezy.To be brief, I can't reproduce the problem now. But thanks though.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. My system has hundreds of packages depending on libsqlite3-0, so many that I would guess I couldn't even boot if I purged as you suggested.

Comment: @Buttons840 My suggestion was conditional; it's clear it doesn't make sense in your case.